# Angular 6 document:pointerup get element where mouse is released

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular6

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to get the container by class or id where the mouse is released.

In other words, I'm working on a drag and drop directive and everything is working. However, I need to detect where is the mouse pointer been released getting the container so I can add data to such container.

For this, I'm using  pointerup event

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you use: document.elementFromPoint(x, y); in your mouseup/pointerup method?

Comment: hey thanks for your comment... I actually ended finding a work around by calculating the area vs X and Y where the mouse is released

Comment: interesting;) I had similar code snippet i was working on the the document.elementFromPoint method works great with the only caveat that normally in Angular you want to avoid such direct Dom interaction.